# How to determine if individual is related to a given population

Tags: hypothesis-testing, descriptive-statistics, uniform-distribution

I would appriciate your help in the following problem:
I've been told that the bonobos height is uniformly distributed, with a,b equal to [70,76] respectivly.
In this group, one individual (height=70.1cm) is suspected to be from another species which has a shorter hight. I need to conduct an hypothesis test to settle the issue with alpha=0.05.
I calculated the confidance interval for a,b: 
α∈[68.1,70.2]
β∈[75.6,77.7]
How should i approch it?

thanks in advance

Comment: Do you know the relative proportions of the two species in the area?

Comment: Uniform distribution of bonobo heights seems fanciful. Is this a textbook problem?